Windows.Media.Capture Unable to obtain H264 format for USB camera
I want to obtain USB camera format and resolution through Windows.Media.Capture.
My USB camera supports MJPG, H264 and H265 formats, but now I can only obtain MJPG and H265 through Windows.Media. H264 format can never be obtained, what is the reason for this?

Can you share more detail how to obtain your camera profile?
